# How to make margins even in displayed equations?

Tags: margins

Whenever I write a displayed equation like

```
$$0\longrightarrow A\longrightarrow B$$
```

the top margin is much bigger than the bottom margin (around four times larger). I am trying to make the bottom margin as big as the top margin, but I don't know how. Can this be adjusted globally?

This happens with tikzcd, too, for example with

```
 \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small]
{}&\overset{3}{\scriptstyle \bullet} \arrow[dl,swap,"\alpha" ]&{}\\
{} \underset{4}{\scriptstyle \bullet} &{}& \underset{2}{\scriptstyle \bullet}\arrow[ll,"\delta"]\arrow[ul,swap,"\beta"] & & \underset{1}{\scriptstyle\bullet}\arrow[ll,"\alpha"]
\end{tikzcd}
```

but in this case no separation from the text is produced, and it looks awful.

Comment: As this doesn't happen normally, you may have to provide a MWE. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)  BTW, if you are using LaTeX, use `\[...\]` over `$$...$$`.

Comment: That's not an inline equation.   For inline equations you should use single $'s.  For displayed equations, use something like `\begin{equation}` or `\begin{gather}`.

Comment: @HarishKumar I have provided an example of  a tikz code I want centered and displayed.

Comment: @Mico Should I upload the code somewhere? I am now getting four "underfull \vbox (badness 10000)" warnings.

Comment: Please start the code with `\documentclass{...}` and end at `\end{document}` so that the problem you are describing can be reproduced. It is difficult to recreate your situation from scratch. I get this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/TskdH.png

Comment: add the example into your question (make it complete but small enough to just add inline). If you have a blank line before your equation, that is th eerror, but without seeing any example, hard to guess.

Comment: I only see the math asymmetry if I don't load amsmath.

Comment: What is really weird is that you can't put tikzcd into \fbox for \parbox.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Please, make an example showing the issue. Otherwise no diagnosis is possible.

Comment: @egreg The problem is the code is not too short, and I cannot be sure what is generating the problem. Hence, I might paste a piece of code which is problem-free and give no information. Should I upload the whole code?

Answer (score 3):

I don't see a problem with `tikz-cd`, other than all the hoops I had to jump through to put it into a `\fbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\newsavebox{\tempbox}
\begin{document}

\fbox{\parbox{0.9\textwidth}%
{\[ 0\longrightarrow A\longrightarrow B \]}}

\setbox\tempbox=\hbox{\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small]
{}&\overset{3}{\scriptstyle \bullet} \arrow[dl,swap,"\alpha" ]&{}\\
{} \underset{4}{\scriptstyle \bullet} &{}& \underset{2}{\scriptstyle \bullet}\arrow[ll,"\delta"]\arrow[ul,swap,"\beta"] & & \underset{1}{\scriptstyle\bullet}\arrow[ll,"\alpha"]
\end{tikzcd}}%
\fbox{\usebox{\tempbox}}

\end{document}
```

[image: boxed items]

I should mention that once you have something in `\fbox` you can set `\fboxrule=0pt` and adjust `\fboxsep` to create larger margins.

Comment: The comparison should use `\fbox{\parbox{\textwidth}{\[\begin{tikzcd}...\end{tikzcd}\]}}`

Comment: @egreg - It's not a comparison; two separate problems..